# Using media query for an image not working correctly

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my Project, I set my background to an image I chose.

The code for that is here:

```
<body>
    <img class="backgroundimg" src="{% static 'spotifywallpaper.jpg' %}" style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1;'>
</body>
```

I then use a media query in css. I am new to these queries and development in general, so please tell me if I am doing anything wrong or in an inefficient away.

My query basically says If the width of the page is 700px or less, set the image width to 100%. When testing this, my image doesn't refit to the page, instead stretches inwards causing a horrible effect to the image.

Here's my media query code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .backgroundimg {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why this isn't working? Thank you.

UPDATED:

**CSS**

```
.mydiv {
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/667865.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydiv">
    Placeholder
</div>
```

This code does not work correctly. I background to function exactly the same as it did with the image tag, this time with a div.

**UPDATE 2:**
This code does not set the width and height of the image to 100% of the page as expected.

**HTML**

```
<img class="bgimage"src="{% static 'spotifywallpaper.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

**CSS**

```
.bgimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: But you already set `width: 100%` on `style` and this has bigger priority than CSS media query. But still - media query does nothing different from normal behavior. Can you provide SO Snippet to see what you mean? Also, why not use it as background image instead?

Comment: dont set height to 100% it will stretch the image (combined with witdh: 100%)

Comment: also don't use z-index:-1, only use positive numbers

Comment: @Ruben Ah, So how would I add this functionality without stretching the image?

Comment: @Justinas Hey friend, a snippet of what? And also what do you mean when setting it as background-image. Also if I did set it as background-image, how would I implement the functionality I want. All I want is for the image not to stretch when the width hits 700px.

Comment: Just FYI, don't forget your _alt text_  property on your img tag. <img src="whatever' alt="spotify wallpaper" /> as this is an accessibility issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the image to not be ugly while streching it on 100% of width

you can use `object-fit` property

e.g:

```
img{
    width: //blabla
    height: //blabla
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

Also if you are using media query to change width on screen change you should not have width and height defined in inline style and I believe you know what inline styling is :d <3

**Update:**
Note that `object-fit` property is for img tag, but if you are going to use set background by using `<img>` tag it is bad practice you should use `<div>` instead with `background-image:url('/images/someimage.png')` property because div has much more efficent ways of manipulating background images.
Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) on the left on mentioned link, there are list of `background properties`

```
  .mydiv {
              background-image: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/667865.jpg');
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-size:cover;
            } 

<div class="mydiv">
    Placeholder
</div>
```

for more to know about `background-size` property checkout [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202028/discussion-on-answer-by-man-of-knowledge-using-media-query-for-an-image-not-work).

Answer (score 0):

First, you gave it inline code, inline code is stronger than external code so your media query code won't work for example

```
<div id="test" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

And in css file you gave

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
  #test {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

The result will be red background for all screen sizes because the inline code is stronger than the external code. 
Try to transfer the inline code to the CSS file like this

```
#test {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
  #test {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```